# jQuery - my selector is also selecting another img element

Tags: jquery, css

Here is my working selector: `$('div' + chapter + ' img')`.

here is what is in chapter: `var chapter = $('#mini_chapter_' + id);`
 so for all intents and purposes can be

```
$('div#minichapter_05 img')
```

Here is what I am trying to select:

```
<div id="mini_chapter_5" class="mini_chapter" >
        <div class="illustrationurl">
         <img src"../../Img/image.jpg>   
        </div>
</div>
```

It does select the nested image element but also is for some odd reason selecting
an element no place near the other elements shown here:

```
<div class="page">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="title">
           <h1>
            <img runat="server" class="gzk_logo" src="~/Img/gzklogouse.jpg"/>
```

Can some on tell me why this may be happening and how to fix it?

Thanks
Adam

Comment: Shouldn't `var chapter = '#mini_chapter_5'` and not a jQuery Object? or perhaps you want to use the `jQuery.attr("id")`?

Comment: If possible, use `#minichapter_05` instead of `div#minichapter_05`. There is no reason to use the tag name along with an ID selector.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#' + chapter.attr('id') + ' img').
```

In your selector you are putting object into string like chapter. chapter in your case is object not string, what you need to do is put id of chapter, like I did it above.

Comment: I'd upvote if your answer provided some explanation in addition to code. Generally speaking, if all the person needed was code, they'd know how to write it themselves. The explanation of *why* this is correct is more valuable than the code.

Comment: you don't neet that `div`. `$('#' + chapter.attr('id') + ' img')` is faster.

Answer (score 1):

try adding `:first` to the img selector. That way you only select the first img element. Or you can try `$('div#minichapter_05').find('img')`

Comment: the second solution will grab the div element then only search its direct children for the img element.

Answer (score 1):

If this line is truly accurate:

```
var chapter = $('#mini_chapter_' + id);
```

then you are setting "chapter" equal to the object #mini_chapter_5.

Try changing the line to:

```
var chapter = '#mini_chapter_' + id;
```

This way you will be setting it equal to text, allowing for proper insertion into your selector.